# Remove Emoji with PySpark

Tags: pyspark, nlp, emoji

I want to use PySpark to efficiently remove Emoji (e.g., `:-)`) from 1 billion records. How could I achieve this using pyspark syntax?

Comment: Do you mean emoji or emoticons? Those are 2 different things

Comment: Also you should probably create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples)

Comment: This topic is super-interesting but your question way too broad, hence offtopic for SO. To make it on-topic for SO, can you fix it by adding example data and example code. Do you a) have a list of all the emojis you might encounter, or are you b) looking for a pretrained model that has a decent list, or c) do you want to learn them (hard, but doable)? (I've been working on this exact task recently, and I can tell you a) is manual, b) is seriously fallible, but c) is pretty hard)

Answer (score 0):

use `regexp_replace` pyspark function